# Why libgdx is filling heap?

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

I was just looking arouns the heap covered by my game with the oracle jconsole. What I saw was heap was increasing continuously. I don't know why. My program is not doning anything. You may see my code. I want to know if it is a bug with libgdx?? Or I'm wrong some where.

Libgdx version: 1.9.9-SNAPSHOT

[image]

```
package sng.urrsm.streetfall;

import com.badlogic.gdx.Game;

public class StreetFall extends Game {

    @Override
    public void create() { 

    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {

    }

}
```

Comment: Create a few memory dumps and compare those to see what's that memory used for. In general, an increasing heap usage, especially if it's just a few megabytes, doesn't have to mean there's a problem. It might just be objects like position vectors, transformation matrices, buffers etc. being created each frame and not being garbage collected yet.

Comment: The usual heap view is a sawtooth pattern. Gradually the line goes up because objects are being created behind the scenes every tick, but eventually a GC should be triggered and then the line drops down again.

Comment: Thomas the heap is increasing continuously without any fall. Please tell how I can create few memory dumps?

Comment: Gimby I've tried to add System.gc() in render() but it eats up the process :(

Comment: Have a look at the MBeans tab, there you should find `com.sun.management > type=HotSpotDiagnostic` which has a `dumpHeap` method. Alternatively use jvisualvm which has a button on the memory view.

Comment: Don't use `gc()` yourself, just let the VM handle it. If you don't want your game to take so much memory (albeit 20mb is not much) then you can always restrict the max heap size on startup up providing a VM option (-Xmx for Oracle's VM) .

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/k94k5p7 Have a look on dumpHeap

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about it, this is normal behaviour.

While your game is running, there a lot of actions happening. Libgdx creates objects all the time for rendering stuff and all the things happening in the background. In Java these objects are not garbage collected until there is a reason to do so (memory required). Until you don´t get any OOM exceptions, you are fine.